# Create a mongodb collection index with expireAfterSeconds using pymongo

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I have a collection in mongodb. In my python program, I have a variable named coll point at it. I want to create an index on a specified field, `digestedOn`, which will cause expiration of the record after 7776000 seconds.

I know how to create a simple index in python: `coll.create_index([( "digestedOn", pymongo.ASCENDING)])`. Where do I stick the `{"expireAfterSeconds": 7776000}` part?

Here's my whole program, I need the last line fixed so that the index is created with expireAfterSeconds.

```
import pymongo
import ssl

def connect_to_mongo(host, port, ssls, user, password, auth_source):
    return pymongo.MongoClient(host, port, ssl=ssls, username=user, ssl_cert_reqs=ssl.CERT_NONE,
                               password=password, authSource=auth_source,
                               authMechanism='SCRAM-SHA-1', maxPoolSize=None)

client = connect_to_mongo(host="10.10.10.10", port=27017, ssls=True, user="user",
                          password="password",auth_source="admin")
db = client['logs']
colnames = db.list_collection_names()
coll = db[colnames[0]]
coll.create_index([( "digestedOn", pymongo.ASCENDING )])
```

Comment: This is explained in documentation. https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.create_index

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just pass it as a named parameter:

```
coll.create_index([( "digestedOn", pymongo.ASCENDING )], expireAfterSeconds=7776000)
```